# input validation patterns in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, input

My application is responsible for moving / creating / copying / deleting files on operating system. 
It exposes some http REST endpoints which are then called by other services to execute the task...

Naturally I have to validate various input params:
- usernames have rules that they must conform
- paths cannot include '..' and some other custom rules that are relevant to my application
- username can be valid, but if the user doesn't exist on the system then I must throw an exception

I must do all those checks before doing anything on the filesystem...

To solve this I created a class with all the validation logic and then just validate every parameter in the controllers by calling relevant function in the validator class.

I find this solution to not be clean. I'd rather implement something like this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

what are other ways of doing input validation?

Comment: take a look at https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/

Comment: Yeah, using `validation annotations` are better than anything to implement. Even you can create a custom `validation annotation` but if you need to implement additional logic then you should use `Custom Validators` for you implementatin.